# I'm looking for a viewer which can display the exported JSON(PHP Style) data out of any Drupal View?

Tags: json, drupal, view, export

As you all know there is an Export "Button" when you Click(in Drupal) on your View(e.g. Customer Data etc.). So I'd like to visualize somehow the data I geht here(which is unfortunately JSON Objects in PHP Style). Most Viewers & Readers (e.g. this here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ or some other SW solutions) can't read this Type of JSON!

I'm aware of the possibility of parsing this Exported JSON Data in php but I'm lookin for a more friendly solution.

Thanxx out there!
George

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'PHP style JSON' (I'm quite sure such a thing doesn't exist) it's a PHP array!

Either grab the [views datasource module](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) which can export views as JSON/XML natively, or simply run the PHP output through [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

If the output looks like this:

```
$view = array(
  'something' => 'something',
  ...
);
```

Then you need to run `$string = json_encode($view); echo $string;`.

That will output the View as a JSON object/array :-)

Comment: No problem glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer so anyone else coming to this page will know their search for an answer is over :)